# How to show that a given polynomial is irreducible in a cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I'm beginning to study McCarthy's *Algebraic Extensions of Fields*, and one of the first problems is to give a factorization of $x^4 + 1$ in $K[x]$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $a$ is a root of $x^4+1$ (thus, if I understood everything correctly, $a$ is a root of unity and $K$ is actually a cyclotomic field, hence the title of the question).

It's not difficult to show that $x^4+1 = (x-a)(x^3 + ax^2 + a^2x + a^3)$ in $K[x]$, using the fact that $a^4+1=0$. But I have no clue about how to show that the factors are irreducible. I thought about applying Eisenstein's criterion, but then got stuck over whether $a$ is a prime in the ring of algebraic integers of $Q(a)$. Is this the correct way?

It'd be nice to know a general procedure for this type of question.

Comment: Nah, they are not irreducible. The roots of $x^4 + 1 = \Phi_8\left(x\right)$ are the four primitive $8$-th roots of unity. If $a$ is one of them, then $a^3, a^5, a^7$ are the others, and thus $x^4 + 1 = \left(x-a\right)\left(x-a^3\right)\left(x-a^5\right)\left(x-a^7\right)$.

Comment: And no, $a$ is not a prime in any ring, because it is invertible ($a^8 = 1$). Invertible elements are not prime by definition of "prime".

Comment: @darijgrinberg - That's very useful. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg (though I'd still like to know if there are other ways of testing for irreducibility in cyclotomic fields)

Comment: I think the last question is the real question here :)

Comment: Being a very computational kind of guy, I’m hoping that you’re well aware that the four roots of $X^4+1$ are $(\pm1\pm i)/\sqrt2$ , and that as @darijgrinberg says, they all are odd powers of any one of them.